# Ant-task don't work with java 9

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, ant, inno-setup

I hope you can help me.

I make a package with the ant build tool, java 8 works fine, but with java 9 i have a exception.
I do not understand why, please help me

For the installer, I use Inno Setup 5.
My IDE is Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a).

the exception

```
    Buildfile: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build.xml
setup-staging-area:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\externalLibs
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\externalFiles
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\project
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\projectRefs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\externalLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\externalFiles
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\project
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\projectRefs
     [copy] Copying 42 files to D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\project
do-compile:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build\src
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build\libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build\classes
  [copydir] DEPRECATED - The copydir task is deprecated.  Use copy instead.
  [copydir] Copying 1 file to D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\externalFiles
  [copydir] DEPRECATED - The copydir task is deprecated.  Use copy instead.
  [copydir] Copying 6 files to D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build\libs
     [copy] Copying 42 files to D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build\src
     [copy] Copying 22 files to D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build\classes
     [copy] Copied 14 empty directories to 3 empty directories under    D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build\classes
    init-fx-tasks:
    do-deploy:
    [copy] Copying 1 file to D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build \classes\META-INF
    "Adding modules: [java.rmi, java.sql, javafx.web, jdk.charsets, java.logging, java.xml.crypto, java.xml, jdk.xml.dom, jdk.jfr, java.datatransfer, jdk.packager.services, jdk.httpserver, javafx.base, jdk.net, java.desktop, java.naming, javafx.controls, java.prefs, java.security.sasl, jdk.naming.rmi, jdk.zipfs, java.base, jdk.crypto.ec, jdk.management.agent, java.management, java.sql.rowset, javafx.swing, jdk.jsobject, jdk.sctp, java.smartcardio, jdk.unsupported, jdk.jdwp.agent, jdk.scripting.nashorn, java.instrument,  java.security.jgss, jdk.management, java.compiler, javafx.graphics,  jdk.security.auth, java.scripting, javafx.fxml, jdk.dynalink, javafx.media,  jdk.accessibility, java.management.rmi, jdk.naming.dns, jdk.security.jgss,  jdk.localedata] to runtime image."
    [fx:deploy] java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 2 command [[C:\Program  Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe, /oD:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7  v2\build\deploy, C:\Users\DH\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15157392799151375137 \images\win-exe.image\OE 7.iss] in C:\Users\DH\AppData\Local \Temp\fxbundler15157392799151375137\images\win-exe.image
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.packager/com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:169)
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.packager/com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:142)
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.packager/com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:136)
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.packager/com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.buildEXE(WinExeBundler.java:703)
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.packager/com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.bundle(WinExeBundler.java:372)
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.packager/com.oracle.tools.packager.windows.WinExeBundler.execute(WinExeBundler.java:174)
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.packager/com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateNativeBundles(PackagerLib.java:371)
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.packager/com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerLib.generateDeploymentPackages(PackagerLib.java:348)
    [fx:deploy]     at com.sun.javafx.tools.ant.DeployFXTask.execute(DeployFXTask.java:310)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    [fx:deploy]     at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [fx:deploy]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [fx:deploy]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
    [fx:deploy]     at  org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:460)
    [fx:deploy]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntR unner.java:142)

    BUILD FAILED
    D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7 v2\build\build.xml:191: Error: Bundler  "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle.

    Total time: 8 seconds
```

What is it? I still wanted to post the build.xml, but I get this error
"It looks like your post is mostly code, please add some more details."

Comment: You try to do that build command manually from the console. From what I can see you have spaces where you shouldn’t and might be missing quotes around some parameters.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I have tried to do that build command manually from the console, but i have the same exception.

Comment: Exactly. So, fix it to work from the command line first.

Comment: ok, but I have no idea what else to try, I have not worked with ant for so long

Comment: I am sorry but I don’t know “ant”. I am just telling you that your inno compiler line is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

I found the error.

Ant creates a temporary folder in which folder the data for the package is copied and now it is crazy.

I run the script with Java 8, the file "OE 7.iss" is created.

```
C:\Users\DH\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15157392799151375137 \images\win-exe.image\OE 7.iss
```

I run the script with Java 9, the file "OE7.iss" is created, he
removes the space in the program name and can not find the file

```
C:\Users\DH\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15157392799151375137 \images\win-exe.image\OE7.iss
```

I just changed the java version, nothing else.

I was able to fix this error, I changed the program name to "OE7", but now I have new errors again

Now the package is created (with Java 9) without "OE7.iss (Inno Setup)" and external libs, when i compile it with java 8, it works fine

my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="Build" default="do-deploy" basedir="."  xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

<property name="project.Folder" value="Build"/>
<property name="publisher" value="Indivikar AG"/>
<property name="native.Bundles" value="exe"/>
<property name="title" value="OE7"/>
<property name="version" value="1.0.0"/>
<property name="main.Class" value="application.StageStartOE7"/>
<!-- <property name="Java.Version" value="jdk1.8.0_151"/> -->
<property name="Java.Version" value="jdk-9.0.4"/>


<property name="project.Path" value="D:\Workspace BuildTest\OE7"/>      
<property name="lib.Path" value="${project.Path}\lib"/> 

<target name="init-fx-tasks">
    <path id="fxant">
        <filelist>
            <file name="C:\Program Files\Java\${Java.Version}\lib\ant-javafx.jar"/>
            <file name="C:\Program Files\Java\${Java.Version}\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar"/>
            <file name="${basedir}"/>
        </filelist>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="com/sun/javafx/tools/ant/antlib.xml"
        uri="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant"
        classpathref="fxant"/>      
</target>

<target name="setup-staging-area">
    <delete dir="externalLibs" />
    <delete dir="externalFiles" />
    <delete dir="project" />
    <delete dir="projectRefs" />

    <mkdir dir="externalLibs" />    
    <mkdir dir="externalFiles" />
    <mkdir dir="project" />
    <mkdir dir="projectRefs" />

    <copy todir="project">
        <fileset dir="${project.Path}">
            <include name="src/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name='do-compile'>
    <delete dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/src" />
    <mkdir dir="build/libs" />
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />


    <!-- Copy project-libs references -->   
     <copydir src="${lib.Path}"
               dest="${basedir}\build\libs"
               includes="**/*.jar"
               excludes="**/Test.java"
     />

    <copy todir="build/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <!-- Copy project sources itself -->
    <copy todir="build/src">
        <fileset dir="project/src">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <javac includeantruntime="false" source="9" target="9" srcdir="build/src" destdir="build/classes" encoding="Cp1252">
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="build/libs">
                <include name="*"/>
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>

    <!-- Copy over none Java-Files -->
    <copy todir="build/classes">
    <fileset dir="project/src">
        <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
    </copy>

</target>
<target name="do-deploy" depends="setup-staging-area, do-compile, init-fx-tasks">
    <delete file="dist"/>       
    <delete file="deploy" />

    <mkdir dir="dist" />
    <mkdir dir="dist/libs" />

    <copy todir="dist/libs">
        <fileset dir="externalLibs">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <fx:resources id="appRes">
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="${project.Folder}.jar"/>           
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="libs/*"/>
        <fx:fileset dir="dist" includes="resources/**"/>
    </fx:resources>

    <fx:application id="fxApplication"
        name="${title}"
        mainClass="${main.Class}"
        version="${version}"
    />

    <mkdir dir="build/classes/META-INF" />

    <fx:jar destfile="dist/Build.jar">
        <fx:application refid="fxApplication"/>
        <fileset dir="build/classes">
        </fileset>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${publisher}"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${title}"/>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${version}"/>
            <attribute name="JavaFX-Feature-Proxy" value="None"/>
        </manifest>
    </fx:jar>

    <mkdir dir="deploy" />

    <fx:deploy
        embedJNLP="false"
        extension="false"
        includeDT="false"
        offlineAllowed="true"
        outdir="${basedir}/deploy"          
        outfile="Build" nativeBundles="${native.Bundles}"
        updatemode="background" 
        verbose="true" >


        <fx:info title="Build" vendor="${publisher}"/>

        <fx:application refId="fxApplication"/>
        <fx:resources refid="appRes"/>
    </fx:deploy>
</target>

</project>
```

if I know more, I will contact you again

Comment: I did test with Java 10.0.1 and had a failed Ant build "fx:deploy" task as well. In Java 8 the build runs fine. In Java 9 and 10.0.1 it fails. After removing the spaces from the application title, like you suggested, the build succeeded in Java 10.0.1. I had to change the file name of the icon and setup icon as well to reflect the change of the application title without spaces. The installer icon itself is still set back to default Java icon. I hope there will be a fix or at least a better workaround to keep the spaces in the application name as it worked in Java 8.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug. After Java 8, the javafxpackager ant-task no longer accepts [space] characters. There is a bug report in Oracle website:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202960

But it is closed as "Won't Fix". As for the explanation on why they won't fix this, I found this comment from one of Oracle engineers:

> We are working on opportunity to propose some new tool to address this
> functionality, but it is too early to share details as this is under
> discussion.

So it appears that Oracle will soon retire Javafx ant-task in favor something else. But I don't know what or when :(

**Update 1:**

In Java 11 Oracle will retire JavaPackager but will introduce a new packager called JPackager. It will no longer include support for ant scripts; only command line. The details can be found here:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200758

**Update 2:**
As @mipa pointed out in comments, JavaPackager will be removed from Java 11 but there won't be a replacement for it until Java 12 :(

**Update 3:**
Java 15+ now has jpackage which is much better than the old JavaPackager. It does not require ant task and very easy to use via command line.

Comment: The Update is only partially correct. Yes, the JavaPackager will be retired. No, the new packager will not be available in Java 11. As it looks now, there will be no packager at all in Java 11. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2018-May/021943.html

Answer (score 1):

You have this line in your log:

> `[fx:deploy] java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 2 command [[C:\Program  Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe, /oD:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7  v2\build\deploy, C:\Users\DH\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15157392799151375137 \images\win-exe.image\OE 7.iss]`

Now, I would say you have some problems with that line of code.

- > `C:\Program  Files (x86)`

Does the path really have **two spaces**? Shouldn't it be:

`C:\Program Files (x86)`

---

- > `Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe,`

What is that **comma** at the end? Shouldn't it be:

`Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe`

---

- `/oD:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7  v2\build\deploy`

Your path has **spaces** in it. It is a very weird path and I might even be wrong. Only you can confirm. But you need **quotes**. Something like:

`/o"D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7  v2\build\deploy"`

---

- `, C:\Users\DH\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15157392799151375137 \images\win-exe.image\OE 7.iss`

Again, you have a **comma** at the start, and you are not wrapping the path to the script file in **quotes**. Something like:

`"C:\Users\DH\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15157392799151375137 \images\win-exe.image\OE 7.iss"`

---

So, putting it all together:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe /o"D:\Workspace BuildTest\HT .-. OE7  v2\build\deploy" "C:\Users\DH\AppData\Local\Temp\fxbundler15157392799151375137 \images\win-exe.image\OE 7.iss"
```

So:

1. Validate all of your **paths** to make sure they are **correct**.
2. Put `" ... "` around your paths since they have spaces.

The help for [ISCC](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_compilercmdline.htm) provides more details.